# How to add all boxes width in one variable using jquery / javascript

Tags: jquery

i want calculate or add width of all box width in one variable. should i use loop or something like that. please suggest

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style>
        .container { 
            width: 610px; 
            overflow: hidden; 
            position: relative; 
            height: 300px;
        }
        .con { position:absolute; left:0; width:2000px}
        .box { float:left; width:200px; 
               height:200px; margin-right:5px; 
               background:#F00; margin-top:5px;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            $('a').click(function (){
                alert($('.box').width())
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="con">
            <div class="box">df</div>
            <div class="box">adfa</div>
            <div class="box">asdf</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">click</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over each `.box` element using `.each()` and add the width to a variable:

```
$('a').click(function(ev){
    var totalWidth = 0;
    $('.box').each(function(i, el){
        totalWidth += $(this).width();
    }
    alert(totalWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This single expression using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) will return the total width:

```
var total = $('.box').get().reduce(function(prev, current, index, array) {
    return prev + current.offsetWidth;
}, 0);
```

Use `$(current).width()` or related variants if the DOM `.offsetWidth` isn't the metric you want.

Comment: Nice solution, but only available in JS 1.8+ (not for <=IE8)

Comment: @mVChr FWIW, IMHO everyone should use the newer functions - they make for cleaner code.  Use a shim to support older browsers.  There's one for `.reduce` in the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a loop, you can use each() with jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Something like that :

```
$('a').click(function (){
    $('div').each(function (){
        //TO DO FOR EACH DIV ON YOUR PAGE
    });
});
```